# ES6 Modules - difference in import formats

Tags: module, ecmascript-6

Given I have two imports:

```
import { createDevTools } from 'redux-devtools';
import LogMonitor from 'redux-devtools-log-monitor';
```

What is the difference between these two?

I understand that `LogMonitor` is the "default" export, and that the bracketed import can import several different exports at once in a comma delimited list. However, is there some difference in the usage?

I feel like I am missing some fundamental.

Comment: No, both `createDevTools` and `LogMonitor` are exactly the same type of variable.

Answer (score 2):

> However, is there some difference in the usage?

No. Default and named imports/exports can have any JavaScript value. It really just depends on how the module you are importing is organized.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { createDevTools } from 'redux-devtools';
```

is a shorthand for:

```
 import DevTools from 'redux-devtools';
 const createDevTools = DevTools.createDevTools;
```

So your going directly to the property of your default export object.

Answer (score 0):

If still, someone is looking for further details with simple example. Look at the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

> The import statement is used to import bindings which are exported by
>   another module. Imported modules are in strict mode whether you
>   declare them as such or not. The import statement cannot be used in
>   embedded scripts unless such script has a type="module"

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export } from "module-name";
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
```